# Can a typescript class be injected into a JavaScript controller?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a TypeScript class and a JavaScript controller separately. The TypeScript class is working as a service, whereas the JavaScript controller needs the Typescript class in order to do something with it. My problem: **how do I do this?**

Thoughts: I know that the AngularJS javascript controller won't allow for `import` statements, so is it possible do access the TypeScript class and its public contents via dependency injection?

Javascript controller:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('testModule')
    .controller('testModule.TestCtrl', TestCtrl);

  TestCtrl.$inject = [
    'testService' // <--- inject here? Note: not sure about this
  ];

  function TestCtrl(testService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      // do stuff
    };

    ctrl.useTestService = function() {
      this.result = testService.makeItRain();
    };
  }

})();
```

Typescript Service

```js
import { SomeStuffThatIsNeeded } from 'some/folder/structure';

export class TestService {

  static $name = 'TestService';
  static $inject = ['$window', '$location'];

  constructor(private $window: any, private $location: any) {
  }

  makeItRain() {
    this.doTheWaterDance();
  }

  private doTheWaterDance(): string {
    return 'get creative!'
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have an understanding of what is going on. You need to understand that Typescript code will transpile to regular JavaScript code. You then will need a module library that can retrieve the module. You can't mix non modular JavaScript code with code that is implemented for a module system.

Comment: you are right, I am learning which is why I realize that I asked such a silly question, regardless this is how you learn. My online research was not giving me good answers because of the nature of my question so I required clarification. Please feel free to expand on your comment

Comment: Can you write the JavaScript controller code into Typescript? The easiest way for you to learn would be to use Plunker and create a new project with AngularJS+Typescript. Here's a link of a project: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:qvZ8Iri6jRUioBEDsa32

Comment: I normally would find this (update to typescript) to be the *best* solution, however the example I am working on is specific to a component which will not currently be updated into typescript, so I have to deal with it for now :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, Yes. All you need to do, is to register that class with Angular as a Service.

```
import { TestService } from './TestService';
angular
    .module('testModule')
    .service('testService', TestService);
```